# SQL Server for xml path add attributes and values

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

I want to create an xml node that contains attributes as well as values.

Example:

```
<mynode attr1="hello">world</mynode>
```

I understand that

```
SELECT 'hello' as '@attr1'
```

creates at least mynode, but how to attach "world" then?

I tried

```
SELECT 'world' as 'mynode/[@attr1=hello]'
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a basic example:

```
SELECT ( SELECT 'White' AS Color1,
'Blue' AS Color2,
'Black' AS Color3,
'Light' AS 'Color4/@Special',
'Green' AS Color4,
'Red' AS Color5
 FOR
 XML PATH('Colors'),
 TYPE
 ),
 ( SELECT 'Apple' AS Fruits1,
 'Pineapple' AS Fruits2,
 'Grapes' AS Fruits3,
 'Melon' AS Fruits4
 FOR
 XML PATH('Fruits'),
 TYPE
 )
 FOR XML PATH(''),
 ROOT('SampleXML')
```

[image: How to create XML data in SQL SERVER]

---

Please, for more information you can visit this page [SQL SERVER – Simple Example of Creating XML File Using T-SQL](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/12/sql-server-simple-example-of-creating-xml-file-using-t-sql/)

Answer (score 6):

This helps you

```
SELECT TOP 1 
   'someValue' AS '@Attribute',
   'text' 
FOR XML PATH('YourElement'), ROOT('Root')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select 'hello' as [@attr1]
, 'world'
for xml path('mynode')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script enables you to extract all your data from all tables in your database into a single XML file:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 
DECLARE @CMD varchar(max) = ''

DECLARE @AllTablesXML table (XMLData XML)
SELECT @CMD += 
  ';SELECT '''+TABLE_NAME+''' as ''@name'' ,
    (
    SELECT * 
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(T.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(T.TABLE_NAME) +
    'FOR XML PATH (''Columns'') ,type ' + CHAR(10) + '
    )
   FOR XML PATH (''Table''),  type'
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
  --WHERE T.TABLE_NAME in  ('your List of tables') Uncomment if you need to extract specific tables

INSERT INTO @AllTablesXML
EXEC (@CMD) 


SELECT XMLData 
FROM @AllTablesXML
FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT('Alltables')
```

Comment: interesting ... I imagine this would kill/stop a server if the database was sufficiently large.

Comment: This is effective for small databases up to 10GB of data, also depends on your business needs. I used it when I needed to import a database to a third party which specifically requested a XML format in order to incorporate the data with their Big data solution as another source.

Comment: It took 15-20 minutes

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer

```
select 'hello' as [@attr1], 'world' for xml path('mynode')
```

only works because `'world'` is a constant one-row result. It will stop working as you wish if you need multiple rows like in

```
select 'hello' as [@attr1], world 
from 
   (select 'world1' AS world 
    union 
    select 'world2') temp
for xml path('mynode')
```

because it will give you the unwanted result

```
<mynode attr1="hello">
  <world>world1</world>
</mynode>
<mynode attr1="hello">
  <world>world2</world>
</mynode>
```

So, if you are after the result

```
<mynode attr1="hello">world1</mynode>
<mynode attr1="hello">world2</mynode>
```

you have to use

```
select 'hello' as [mynode/@attr1], world as mynode
   (select 'world1' AS world 
    union 
    select 'world2') temp
for xml path('')
```