# SQL FOR XML Path, returning multiple child elements

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath

I require data to be returned from table in following format.

```
<Root>
  <Property name="test1">text1</Property>
  <Property name="test2">text2</Property>
  <Property name="test3">text3</Property>
  <Property name="test4">text4</Property>
</Root>
```

I've tried the code from other post [SQL Server for xml path add attributes and values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237439/sql-server-for-xml-path-add-attributes-and-values) and can get it to work for single line but not multiple.
eg.

```
Select 'test1' as [@name], 'text1'
     FOR XML PATH('Property'), ROOT('Root')
```

Works giving

```
<Root>
  <Property name="test1">text1</Property>
</Root>
```

but

```
Select  'test1' as [@name], 'text1'
       ,'test2' as [@name], 'text2'
       ,'test3' as [@name], 'text3'
       ,'test4' as [@name], 'text4'
     FOR XML PATH('Property'), ROOT('Root')
```

Fails with

Attribute-centric column '@name' must not come after a non-attribute-centric sibling in XML hierarchy in FOR XML PATH.

Cant find how to get the format I require above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element name used i path is repeated for each row returned. If you want to repeat the same element name for one row you need to specify the element name in the column alias and you need to separate the different elements with a empty column value.

```sql
select 'test1' as [Property/@name],
       'text1' as Property,
       null,
       'test2' as [Property/@name],
       'text2' as Property,
       null,
       'test3' as [Property/@name],
       'text3' as Property,
       null,
       'test4' as [Property/@name],
       'text4' as Property
for xml path(''), root('Root');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your desired output using following query:

```
select  T.Name as 'Property/@name', T.[Text] as 'Property'
from 
    (
        select 'test1' as Name, 'text1' as [Text]
        union all 
        select 'test2', 'text2'
        union all
        select 'test3', 'text3'
        union all
        select 'test4', 'text4'
    ) as T
for xml path(''), root('Root')
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeated notes should be rows not columns, so the following would build the required XML:

```
SELECT  t.[@name], t.[text()]
FROM    (VALUES
            ('Test1', 'Text1'),
            ('Test2', 'Text2'),
            ('Test3', 'Text3'),
            ('Test4', 'Text4')
        ) AS t ([@name], [text()])
FOR XML PATH('Property'), ROOT('Root')
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of being rows not columns. That explained my confusion over not being able to select multiples. eg why I couldn't select 'test1' from the column name of a table and text1 as the value from that column. Ill have to figure that out.