# TSQL - Add Attributes to XML when outputting AUTO, TYPE, ELEMENTS

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, stored-procedures

Have a requirement to output a job ticket in XML from MS SQL database. Have created the following stored procedure that is called by passing a unique ID and the XML is output to a directory. This has been working well, however the program receiving the XML now wants an attribute (part number) on one of the parts.

Numbering the part has be achieved using the `ROW_NUMBER()` - however I can't work out how to store this as an attribute.

Current code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EstBinderySig](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EstimateID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EstPartID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EstVersionID] [int] NOT NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK__EstBinderySig] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EstimatePart](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EstimateID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EstimateProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UniquePartNumber] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [EstimateHeaderRef] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](64) NULL,
    [FinishedSizeCode] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [FinishedSizeWidth] [float] NOT NULL,
    [FinishedSizeDepth] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Orientation] [bit] NOT NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK__EstimatePart] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EstVersions](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EstimateID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Quantity] [float] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__EstVersions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MainJobDetails](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [JobNo] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceCustomerCode] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [InvoiceCustomerName] [varchar](64) NULL,
    [JobType] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [JobDesc] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EstimateID] [int] NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK__MainJobDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

SET IDENTITY_INSERT  [dbo].[EstBinderySig] ON;

INSERT [dbo].[EstBinderySig] ([ID],[EstimateID],[EstPartID],[EstVersionID])
VALUES (1269922, 165438, 208492, 150728)
INSERT [dbo].[EstBinderySig] ([ID],[EstimateID],[EstPartID],[EstVersionID])
VALUES (1269923, 165438, 208492, 150729)
INSERT [dbo].[EstBinderySig] ([ID],[EstimateID],[EstPartID],[EstVersionID])
VALUES (1269924, 165438, 208492, 150730)
INSERT [dbo].[EstBinderySig] ([ID],[EstimateID],[EstPartID],[EstVersionID])
VALUES (1269925, 165438, 208492, 150731)
INSERT [dbo].[EstBinderySig] ([ID],[EstimateID],[EstPartID],[EstVersionID])
VALUES (1269926, 165438, 208492, 150727)
INSERT [dbo].[EstBinderySig] ([ID],[EstimateID],[EstPartID],[EstVersionID])
VALUES (1269927, 165438, 208493, 150732)
INSERT [dbo].[EstBinderySig] ([ID],[EstimateID],[EstPartID],[EstVersionID])
VALUES (1269928, 165438, 208493, 150733)
INSERT [dbo].[EstBinderySig] ([ID],[EstimateID],[EstPartID],[EstVersionID])
VALUES (1269929, 165438, 208493, 150734)
INSERT [dbo].[EstBinderySig] ([ID],[EstimateID],[EstPartID],[EstVersionID])
VALUES (1269930, 165438, 208493, 150735)
INSERT [dbo].[EstBinderySig] ([ID],[EstimateID],[EstPartID],[EstVersionID])
VALUES (1269931, 165438, 208493, 150736)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[EstBinderySig] OFF;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[EstimatePart] ON;

INSERT [dbo].[EstimatePart] ([ID],[EstimateID],[EstimateProductID],[UniquePartNumber], [EstimateHeaderRef],[Name],[FinishedSizeCode],[FinishedSizeWidth],[FinishedSizeDepth], [Orientation])
VALUES (208492,165438, 165422,'61EC545B-9D09-4650-AB25-624BED837AC0','122500','Cover','A5', 148,210,0)
INSERT [dbo].[EstimatePart] ([ID],[EstimateID],[EstimateProductID],[UniquePartNumber], [EstimateHeaderRef],[Name],[FinishedSizeCode],[FinishedSizeWidth],[FinishedSizeDepth], [Orientation])
VALUES (208493,165438, 165422,'DB5A9964-5DFB-48F2-9BD1-F7970D8B2843','122500','Text','A5', 148,210,0)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[EstimatePart] OFF;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[EstVersions] ON;

INSERT [dbo].[EstVersions] ([ID],[EstimateID],[Description],[Quantity])
VALUES (150728,165438,'Version 2',1000)
INSERT [dbo].[EstVersions] ([ID],[EstimateID],[Description],[Quantity])
VALUES (150729,165438,'Version 3',1000)
INSERT [dbo].[EstVersions] ([ID],[EstimateID],[Description],[Quantity])
VALUES (150730,165438,'Version 4',1000)
INSERT [dbo].[EstVersions] ([ID],[EstimateID],[Description],[Quantity])
VALUES (150731,165438,'Version 5',1000)
INSERT [dbo].[EstVersions] ([ID],[EstimateID],[Description],[Quantity])
VALUES (150732,165438,'Version 1',1000)
INSERT [dbo].[EstVersions] ([ID],[EstimateID],[Description],[Quantity])
VALUES (150733,165438,'Version 2',1000)
INSERT [dbo].[EstVersions] ([ID],[EstimateID],[Description],[Quantity])
VALUES (150734,165438,'Version 3',1000)
INSERT [dbo].[EstVersions] ([ID],[EstimateID],[Description],[Quantity])
VALUES (150735,165438,'Version 4',1000)
INSERT [dbo].[EstVersions] ([ID],[EstimateID],[Description],[Quantity])
VALUES (150736,165438,'Version 5',1000)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[EstVersions] OFF;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MainJobDetails] ON;

INSERT [dbo].[MainJobDetails] ([ID],[JobNo],[InvoiceCustomerCode],[InvoiceCustomerName] , [JobType], [JobDesc], [EstimateID])
VALUES (65846, '335585', 'XXXXX', 'XXXXX', 'XXXXX', 'XXXXX', 165438)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MainJobDetails] OFF;
GO




    select 

                [Job].[jobno] AS '@JobNo'
                ,[Job].[InvoiceCustomerCode] AS '@CustomerCode'
                ,[dbo].[BCQ_ReplaceAccents]([Job].[JobDesc]) AS '@JobDesc'
                ,[Job].[JobTypeDesc] AS '@JobType'
                ,Job.InvoiceCustomerName AS '@InvoiceCustomerName'
                ,(  SELECT COUNT(ID) 
                    FROM EstimatePart 
                    WHERE EstimateID = Job.EstimateID) AS '@NoOfParts'
               ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Part].[ID] ASC) AS '@PartNo'
               ,[Part].[Name] AS 'PartName'
               ,CAST([Part].[FinishedSizeWidth] AS decimal(10,2)) AS 'Width'
               ,CAST([Part].[FinishedSizeDepth] AS decimal(10,2)) AS 'Depth'
               ,CASE WHEN [Part].[Orientation] = 0 THEN 'P' ELSE 'L' END AS 'Orientation'
               ,CASE WHEN Part.ProcessInksBack + Part.SpotInksBack + Part.MetallicInksBack = 0 then Part.totalpages/2 else Part.totalpages END AS 'PartPages'
               ,[Part].[Description] AS 'StockType'
               ,[Part].[ProcessInksFront] AS 'ProcessInkFront'
               ,[Part].[ProcessInksBack] AS 'ProcessInkBack'
               ,[Part].[SpotInksFront] + [Part].[MetallicInksFront] AS 'SpotColoursFront'
               ,[Part].[SpotInksBack] + [Part].[MetallicInksBack] AS 'SpotColoursBack'
                              ,(             SELECT CONCAT([Version].[Description],' ',[Version].[Quantity]) 
                                             FROM [dbo].[EstBinderySig] [VersionLink] WITH (NOLOCK) 
                                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[EstVersions] [Version] WITH (NOLOCK)
                                                            ON [VersionLink].[EstVersionID] = [Version].[ID]
                                             WHERE [VersionLink].[EstimateID] = [Job].[EstimateID] AND [VersionLink].[EstPartID] = [Part].[ID]
                                             ORDER BY [VersionLink].[ID] ASC
                                             FOR XML AUTO, TYPE, ELEMENTS                                           
                              ) AS 'Version'

FROM

                              [dbo].[MainJobDetails] [Job] 
                              INNER JOIN [dbo].[EstimatePart] [Part] 
                                             ON [Job].[EstimateID] = [Part].[EstimateID]           

WHERE Job.ID = @recordid

FOR XML PATH('Part');
```

This is now giving the following XML Output:

```
   <Part JobNo="XXXXX" IssueNumber="3" CustomerCode="XXXXX" Contact="XXXXX" JobDesc="Sample stitched brochure - versions" DespatchDate="2018-11-23T18:00:00" JobType="Stitched brochure" QTYOrdered="5000" InvoiceCustomerName="XXXXX" ProofType="PDF" NoOfParts="2" Versions="5" TotalPages="100" JobCreator="XXXXX" JobCreatorEmail="XXXXX" Site="XXXXX" Method="XXXXX" DieRef="XXXXX" PartNo="1">
  <PartName>Cover</PartName>
  <Width>148.00</Width>
  <Depth>210.00</Depth>
  <Orientation>P</Orientation>
  <PartPages>4</PartPages>
  <StockType>Chorus Lux Silk 300gsm</StockType>
  <ProcessInkFront>4</ProcessInkFront>
  <ProcessInkBack>4</ProcessInkBack>
  <SpotColoursFront>0</SpotColoursFront>
  <SpotColoursBack>0</SpotColoursBack>
  <Version>
    <VersionLink>Version 2 1000</VersionLink>
    <VersionLink>Version 3 1000</VersionLink>
    <VersionLink>Version 4 1000</VersionLink>
    <VersionLink>Version 5 1000</VersionLink>
    <VersionLink>Version 1 1000</VersionLink>
  </Version>
</Part>
<Part JobNo="XXXXX" IssueNumber="3" CustomerCode="XXXXX" Contact="XXXXX" JobDesc="Sample stitched brochure - versions" DespatchDate="2018-11-23T18:00:00" JobType="Stitched brochure" QTYOrdered="5000" InvoiceCustomerName="XXXXX" ProofType="PDF" NoOfParts="2" Versions="5" TotalPages="100" JobCreator="XXXXX" JobCreatorEmail="XXXXX" Site="XXXXX" Method="XXXXX" DieRef="XXXXX" PartNo="2">
  <PartName>Text</PartName>
  <Width>148.00</Width>
  <Depth>210.00</Depth>
  <Orientation>P</Orientation>
  <PartPages>16</PartPages>
  <ProcessInkFront>4</ProcessInkFront>
  <ProcessInkBack>4</ProcessInkBack>
  <SpotColoursFront>0</SpotColoursFront>
  <SpotColoursBack>0</SpotColoursBack>
  <Version>
    <VersionLink>Version 1 1000</VersionLink>
    <VersionLink>Version 2 1000</VersionLink>
    <VersionLink>Version 3 1000</VersionLink>
    <VersionLink>Version 4 1000</VersionLink>
    <VersionLink>Version 5 1000</VersionLink>
  </Version>
</Part>
```

The desired ouput is:

```
<Job>
  <jobno>XXXXX</jobno>
  <IssueNumber>3</IssueNumber>
  <CustomerCode>XXXXX</CustomerCode>
  <Contact>XXXXX</Contact>
  <JobDesc>Sample stitched brochure - versions</JobDesc>
  <DespatchDate>2018-11-23T18:00:00</DespatchDate>
  <JobType>Stitched brochure</JobType>
  <QTYOrdered>5000</QTYOrdered>
  <InvoiceCustomerName>XXXXX</InvoiceCustomerName>
  <ProofType>PDF</ProofType>
  <NoOfParts>2</NoOfParts>
  <Versions>5</Versions>
  <TotalPages>100</TotalPages>
  <JobCreator>XXXXX</JobCreator>
  <JobCreatorEmail>XXXXX</JobCreatorEmail>
  <Site>XXXXX</Site>
  <Method>XXXXX</Method>
  <DieRef>N/A</DieRef>
  <Part PartNo="1">
    <PartName>Cover</PartName>
    <Width>148.00</Width>
    <Depth>210.00</Depth>
    <Orientation>P</Orientation>
    <PartPages>4</PartPages>
    <StockType>Chorus Lux Silk 300gsm</StockType>
    <ProcessInkFront>4</ProcessInkFront>
    <ProcessInkBack>4</ProcessInkBack>
    <SpotColoursFront>0</SpotColoursFront>
    <SpotColoursBack>0</SpotColoursBack>
    <Version>
      <VersionLink>Version 2 1000</VersionLink>
      <VersionLink>Version 3 1000</VersionLink>
      <VersionLink>Version 4 1000</VersionLink>
      <VersionLink>Version 5 1000</VersionLink>
      <VersionLink>Version 1 1000</VersionLink>
    </Version>
  </Part>
  <Part PartNo="2">
    <PartName>Text</PartName>
    <Width>148.00</Width>
    <Depth>210.00</Depth>
    <Orientation>P</Orientation>
    <PartPages>16</PartPages>
    <ProcessInkFront>4</ProcessInkFront>
    <ProcessInkBack>4</ProcessInkBack>
    <SpotColoursFront>0</SpotColoursFront>
    <SpotColoursBack>0</SpotColoursBack>
    <Version>
      <VersionLink>Version 1 1000</VersionLink>
      <VersionLink>Version 2 1000</VersionLink>
      <VersionLink>Version 3 1000</VersionLink>
      <VersionLink>Version 4 1000</VersionLink>
      <VersionLink>Version 5 1000</VersionLink>
    </Version>
  </Part>
</Job>
```

Comment: I believe you will need to [switch to `FOR XML PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25237439/11683).

Answer (score 0):

Put an `@` before the name of the alias. Note that attribute must be **before** any further nodes. As a (simple) example:

```
SELECT 1 AS [@Partno],
       'test' AS Test       
FOR XML PATH('item'),ROOT('job');
```

This returns the value:

```
<job>
  <item Partno="1">
    <Test>test</Test>
  </item>
</job>
```

If, however, you were to try:

```
SELECT 'test' AS Test,
       1 AS [@Partno]
FOR XML PATH('item'),ROOT('job');
```

You would receive the error:

> Attribute-centric column '@Partno' must not come after a non-attribute-centric sibling in XML hierarchy in FOR XML PATH.

Comment: This is `for xml path`.

Comment: Hadn't noticed that the OP was using `XML AUTO`, but yes, they will need to switch to `PATH`.

Comment: @Larnu - ok have got the attributes working using the FOR XML PATH and @ alias as suggested, but now have to use the fields queried from Job table as attributes as well as they preceed the "Part" query which means they repeat on every Part... is there any way around this?

Comment: Afraid I don't understand what you mean there @user7009628 . Sample data (and the expected result) will really help here; we can then show you how to get the result your want using `PATH`.

Comment: @user7009628 This answer addresses that issue specifically.

Comment: @Larnu - ok have amended the original Q to include all code and full expected result. Hope that clarifies!

Comment: I see expected results @user7009628, I don't see any samples? tehre's no DDL or DML in your question.

Comment: @user7009628 Move the `'@PartNo'` line above the other lines like it is specifically pointed out in this answer.

Comment: @Gserg - I have to move the @ PartNo to the top of the select statement for the code to work (unless every preceeding field has it's alias prefixed with @). This is not the desired location for the field. There is a 1-many relationship between job and part table, the elements from the job table should only appear once in the XML, the elements from the part table are specific for each row. I am trying to get the attribute to show on the part even though it appears after "non-attribute-centric" fields... I can't post DDL/DML as it goes over the character limit!! (Huge tables)...

Comment: You don't need to post the whole table... just 1 (or 2) samples and their expected results is fine, @user7009628. But, as my post says, you can't define sibling attributes before `@PartNo`, or any other centric attributes.

Comment: @user7009628 You can and you should move `@PartNo` to the top of the select statement. In the `PATH` mode the column names define the structure, not the order.

Comment: @GSerg - thanks for persevering however still not getting it. As soon as using PATH mode, all of the fields queried from the Job table will appear in the XML twice (preceeding each part each part in this case). Is it possible to use XML PATH and get the desired result?

Comment: So then supply sample data and and expected result then @user7009628, please. Without it, there's little more we can do to help you.

Comment: @Larnu - I have added the sample data, however due to volume (columns etc.) I had to trim in word processor - hope it's ok!

Comment: Thanks @user7009628 it's really helpful thoiugh if you test your DDL and DML scripts. There are loads of error in it... each time i fix one, I get another.

Comment: After fixing your DDL and DML @user7009628 your sample script doesn't work. Again, a lot of errosr. We don't have the function `[dbo].[BCQ_ReplaceAccents]` and almost all of the columns in the object `[EstimatePart]`.I'm afraid we can't help you if you only give us bits of the pie. Sorry, but good luck.